# Custom dialog box in android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, customdialog

1.This is add button, when I click here I should arise custom dialog box.

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
// add button listener
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

2.This is custom dialog box code

```
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.form);
    dialog.setTitle("Custom dailog");

    TextView uname_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Uname_TV);
    EditText uname_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Uname_ET);
    TextView dname_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Drugname_TV);
    EditText dname_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Drugname_ET);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);

    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (
    context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    noof_times);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <? > parent,
        View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String item1 = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected:" + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <? > arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

I am getting

```
  Null pointer exception at spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I didn't get it, one help out of this error

Comment: Try to identify the textview's with `dialog.findViewById(...)` And, post ur logtrace here.

Comment: check this.. : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10652886/1168654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
```

Try with this line..hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

yeah you will get because

```
TextView uname_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Uname_TV);
EditText uname_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Uname_ET);
TextView dname_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Drugname_TV);
EditText dname_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Drugname_ET);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
```

change these to

```
TextView uname_TV = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Uname_TV);
EditText uname_ET = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Uname_ET);
TextView dname_TV = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Drugname_TV);
EditText dname_ET = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Drugname_ET);
spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
```

Comment: Thanks every one got it ya .:)

Answer (score 0):

You must inflate a layout while making view custom.
Try the code below on the click event:

```
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(YouActivityName.this);
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.form, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(YouActivityName.this);
            builder.setView(view);
            Spinner spinner=(Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
            ArrayAdapter<String > adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
```

Declare the remaining views above in the code.Hope this will help you.